# How do I extract deny from IP from htaccess PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to list IPs that are listed in my htaccess to be denied. I do not want to see the `deny from all` or `allow from`.

Sample IP list:

```
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

allow from 10.10.190.187
deny from 10.10.76.194
deny from 10.10.85.70
deny from 10.10.63.174
deny from 10.10.56.77
deny from 10.10.15.196
```

Desired output:

```
deny from 10.10.76.194
deny from 10.10.85.70
deny from 10.10.63.174
deny from 10.10.56.77
deny from 10.10.15.196
```

Note `allow from 10.10.190.187` and `deny from all` are excluded from desired output.

My current code:

```
$htaccess = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/.htaccess";
$file = $htaccess;
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode("\n", $contents); // this is your array of words
foreach($lines as $line) {
   if (preg_match('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $line, $ip_match)) {
   $ip =  $ip_match[0];
}
$pattern = "/deny from $ip/";
   if (preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $ip_denymatch)) {
      foreach($ip_denymatch[0] as $ipL){
         echo $ipL . "<br>"; 
   }
  }  
}
```

The current output sample is:

```
deny from
deny from 10.10.76.194
deny from 10.10.85.70
deny from 10.10.63.174
deny from 10.10.56.77
deny from 10.10.15.196
```

The output includes the `deny from all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're reading line: `deny from all`, the first `preg_match` return false and `$ip` is empty.

Then when you call `preg_match_all` with `$pattern = "/deny from $ip/";`, the line is matched.

You should use a single `preg_match` like:

```php
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^deny from \d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}$/', $line)) {
        echo $line,"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function is easy to use to read a file line by line into an array.

```
$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

[preg_grep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep) works well for filtering arrays with regular expressions.

```
$arrDeniedIps = preg_grep('/^deny from [0-9.]+/',$lines);
```